# Say Type is Record<string, string> except for 1 key which is type Function?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a typescript type which has this format:

```
type Route = 
  Record<string, string> & { buildUrl: (params: Record<string, string>) => string }
```

So the corresponding object would look like this:

```
const route: Route = {
  base: 'profile',
  param: ':profileId',
  tab1: 'details',
  tab2: 'edit',
  buildUrl: ({ profileId, tab }) => `/profile/${profileId}/${tab}`,
}
```

Note that there will be multiple instances of these `Route` objects, each with their own keys and `buildUrl` function.

Does anyone know how to construct a type which allows this sort of thing? Thanks.

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript which works the way you want; there are various workarounds with various benefits and drawbacks.  Please see the linked question and answers for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but a solution could be something like:

```ts
type Route = {
  parts: Record<string, string>;
  buildUrl: (params: Record<string, string>) => string;
};
```